# dpptam image transport

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting this error running dpptam with a live feed from webcam. I see others with this same error posted around but under different circumstances relating to image transport and ubuntu 16. Can anyone comment of this issue ? Thank you.

```
[ERROR] [1495577785.773462409]: Compressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: bgr8).
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262408/dpptam-image-transport/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be a misunderstanding on my part. Apparently you get this error if you subscribe to a image topic that is not published or is of the wrong type that uses image transport.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0